# yield axios.get() call in Saga changes the pathname to the default location "/"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, connected-react-router

I have have this Saga for retrieving the token from localStorage and sign in the user automatically

```
export function* authCheckState(action) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    const expDate = localStorage.getItem("expDate");
    if (!token) {
        yield put(actions.logout()); 
    } else {
        const expirationDate = new Date(expDate);
        if (expirationDate <= new Date()) {
            yield put(actions.logout());
        } else {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
            const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
            // const loggedInUser = yield axios.get(`/users/${username}`);
            // console.log('HERE');
            yield put(actions.loginSuccess());
            yield put(
                actions.fireTimeout(
                    (expirationDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime())
                    // 10 * 1000 // ms
                )
            );
        }

    }
}
```

So If I visit any path in the application for example '/users' it stays the same after executing the saga.

now the code above as is is working perfectly. However now I want to add an axios call to get some data like this:

```
const loggedInUser = yield axios.get(`/users/${username}`);
// store it in the store.
```

When I add this axios call. I get redirected to the home page "/".

Before: working

[image]

After: not working redirection happens

[image]

Comment: Mot sure if this has anything to do with your router change, but you should be using the ‘call’ api from saga when making your axios request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, I changed the order of the call and now it's working properly!!

```
yield put(actions.loginSuccess());
const loggedInUser = yield axios.get(`/users/${username}`);
yield put(actions.loginSuccess(username, loggedInUser.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment but could not due to less points, may be you should use

```
yield call (Api.fetchUser,username)
```

where `Api.fetchUser` is a function which internally hits the rest api and returns a promise.